# How do I find a named sublayer?

Tags: illustrator-scripting

I have many files with a similar layer structure, but the layer structure is not exactly the same in each of these files.

Each file has layers inside of layers; in other words, nested layers.  One of these layers is called "mat outline", but the exact location changes from file to file.   Again, it could be a sublayer, or a sublayer of a sublayer.  I don't know in advance.

How do I find this layer called "mat outline" in a given file?

I know how to write a nested for-loop that will look at every layer and sublayer down the nested structure, and I can definitely find it. But isn't there an easier way?

Can I write "layers.layers" and get an object that is all sublayers of all layers?

If there is no other way, then I will proceed writing nested for-loops.  I just want to be sure I'm not doing unncessary work.

Comment: Usually you would write the search as recursive.

Comment: At the moment, the concept of a recursive search is a little beyond my scripting abilities, but I can learn it if this is the only way to efficiently do the search.

Comment: I didn't see one approach that would be helpful.  I saw someone who sifted through all the layers and sublayers, and they constructed an object called "all-layers" that consists of all the sublayers from the bottom of the nest/ or tree structure. In other words, this object is the flattened representation of the whole nested structure.  I could then do various searches through "all-layers" for different desired sublayers, and I only need to consruct "all-layers" once. That would save time.

Comment: Think of it like calling search for each member. Usually you dont want to flatten the list because it can get obsoleted.

Comment: Try using the traverse scene function in following post: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104077/replace-bitmap-circles-to-vector-circles-shape-recognition/104099#104099

Comment: @joojaa  I looked at the traverse thing, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be seeing?  Is this a treasure hunt?    joke.

Comment: thats how you get to go through every object and subobject of a scene. Just pass it a function  of what to do for each object